# Emails or memos claiming to be "From the desk of ..."

Tags: terminology

Some people adopt the affectation in a message, memo or email where the sender is identified explicitly in the header of the message that the sender is shown as being "From the desk of Joe Smith" rather than just from "Joe Smith".

In some situations, "From the office of" makes more sense - I take this as meaning that someone on the staff of a politician or senior executive wrote the contents, but that the office holder is happy to be considered as supporting the message.

Is this what Joe Smith is trying to tell us with this construction?

Comment: I have no idea what "from the desk of" is intended to mean, but I knew someone who said that they would never reply to such a message because they refuse to correspond with a piece of furniture.

Comment: @TrevorD or when in a meeting and you have to address the chair ...

Comment: Exactly! (This comment was 18 char. long and yet when I try to send it, I get a message that says it must be at least 15 characters long! I hope this is now long enough!)

Answer (score 4):

“From the desk of” is metaphor.  Similar metaphors are “from the hand of” and “from the pen of”. Specifically, it is a figure of speech known as *synecdoche*[¹](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche) in which a part of a thing refers to the whole. A letter “from the desk of”, “from the hand of”, or “from the pen of” John Doe was written by John Doe.

Synecdoche has been used since antiquity, and your exact phrase has been used as synecdoche for hundreds of years. Here is the earliest example I found online:

> Population is said to be all in all, increase your people, and you need take no account of any other matter, population being the political thermometer ; but such notions, when they walk **from the desk of** the visionary to the cabinet of the statesman, are productive of infinite mischief. In numerous countries and cases, increasing the people is a political evil. (John Almon, 1772, *Letters concerning the present state of England*, p. 136; emphasis added.)[²](http://books.google.com/books?id=aug9AAAAcAAJ)

Note above that words are also figuratively said to “walk”. This is an example of *personification*, another popular figure of speech.[³](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_of_speech)